# Scroll on click not on hover with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, hover, slider

i don't really know jquery so i wanted your help with something..

I found a custom scroller (horizontal slider), which has images in and arrows for navigation.

When you hover over the arrow it automatically starts moving to the right when you hover on the left arrow it goes to the left. What i want is to make it "move" when i click on the arrow and not when i hover on it.

Here's the code of the file,

```
jQuery(function($) {


// check for touchable device
    var isTouch =  false;   
    if( jQuery('html').hasClass('touch') ){     
        isTouch = true;         
    }

    //scrollpane parts
    var scrollPane = jQuery( ".scroll-pane" ),
        scrollContent = jQuery( ".scroll-content" );

    // set scrollInterval
    var scrollInterval = 25, // scroll steps in px
        timer_speed = 15 // scroll timer speed in milliseconds

    // show scroll arrows on hover
    scrollPane.hover( 
        function(){
            jQuery(".scroller-arrow:(.disabled)").stop(false, true).fadeIn();
        },
        function(){ 
            jQuery(".scroller-arrow:(.disabled)").stop(false, true).fadeOut();
        }
    );              

    var speed = 0;      

    function prepareScrollerComponents() {

        if(navigator.platform == 'iPad' || navigator.platform == 'iPhone' || navigator.platform == 'iPod'){
            jQuery("#scroll_left, #scroll_right").css({ display: 'block' });
        }

        $cw = 0;
        jQuery('li.item', scrollContent).each(function(){ 
            $cw = $cw + jQuery(this).outerWidth(true);
        })

        scrollContent.width( $cw );

        // calculate the scrolling speed
        speed = (scrollInterval * 30) / $cw;

        setScrollerWidth();

        if(isTouch === true){

            scrollPane.css({ overflow: 'hidden'}).overscroll({
                direction: 'horizontal'
            }).on('overscroll:dragstart overscroll:dragend overscroll:driftstart overscroll:driftend', function(event){
            })              

        }else{          
            scrollbar.slider('option', 'value', 0);         
        }

        scrollContent.css({ visibility: 'visible' });
        scrollPane.css({ background: 'none' });

    }

    jQuery(window).load(function(){

        prepareScrollerComponents();

    });

    jQuery(window).smartresize(function(){  

        prepareScrollerComponents();

    });


    var slide_handler = function(e, ui) {

        if(isTouch === false){

            if(ui.value == 0){
                jQuery("#scroll_left").addClass('disabled').stop(false, true).fadeOut();
                jQuery("#scroll_right").removeClass('disabled').stop(false, true).fadeIn();
            }

            if(ui.value > 0 && ui.value < 100){
                jQuery("#scroll_left").removeClass('disabled').stop(false, true).fadeIn();
                jQuery("#scroll_right").removeClass('disabled').stop(false, true).fadeIn();
            }
            if(ui.value == 100){
                jQuery("#scroll_left").removeClass('disabled').stop(false, true).fadeIn();
                jQuery("#scroll_right").addClass('disabled').stop(false, true).fadeOut();
            }

        }

        if ( scrollContent.width() > scrollPane.width() ) {
            scrollContent.css( "margin-left", Math.round(
                ui.value / 100 * ( scrollPane.width() - scrollContent.width() )
            ) + "px" );
        } else {
            scrollContent.css( "margin-left", 0 );
        }
    };                  

    //build slider
    if(isTouch === false){
        var scrollbar = jQuery( ".scroll-bar" ).slider({
            slide: slide_handler,
            change: slide_handler
        });
    }

jQuery('.scroll-content-item:last').css({marginRight: 0});

jQuery(window).load(function(){

    if(isTouch === false){                                                      

        // Mousewheel plugin
        jQuery(scrollPane).add(jQuery(scrollPane).find('li')).mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
            var value = scrollbar.slider('option', 'value');

            if (delta >= 0) { value -= speed; }
            else if (delta <= 0) { value += speed; }

            // Ensure that its limited between 0 and 100
            value = Math.max(0, Math.min(100, value));

            scrollbar.slider('option', 'value', value);

            event.preventDefault();

        });

    }

})


var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
var isiPhone = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null;

// trigger for scroll right event
$.fn.mouseenter_trigger_right = function(){

    var maxWidth = ( scrollContent.width() - jQuery(window).width() ) * -1 ;

    timer = setInterval(function() { 

        jQuery("#scroll_left").removeClass('disabled').stop(false, true).fadeIn();

        var slider = jQuery('.scroll-bar');
        var curSlider = slider.slider("option", "value");
        curSlider += speed; // += and -= directions of scroling with MouseWheel

        // Ensure that its limited between 0 and 100
        curSlider = Math.max(0, Math.min(100, curSlider));

        if (curSlider > slider.slider("option", "max")){
            jQuery("#scroll_right").addClass('disabled');
            curSlider = slider.slider("option", "max");
        } else if (curSlider < slider.slider("option", "min")){
            curSlider = slider.slider("option", "min");
        }else{

        }                   

        scrollbar.slider('option', 'value', curSlider);                     

    }, timer_speed);                    

}

// trigger for scroll left event
$.fn.mouseenter_trigger_left = function(){

    timer = setInterval(function() { 

        jQuery("#scroll_right").removeClass('disabled');

        var slider = jQuery('.scroll-bar');;
        var curSlider = slider.slider("option", "value");
        curSlider -= speed; // += and -= directions of scroling with MouseWheel

        // Ensure that its limited between 0 and 100
        curSlider = Math.max(0, Math.min(100, curSlider));                      

        if (curSlider > slider.slider("option", "max")){
            curSlider = slider.slider("option", "max");
        }else if (curSlider < slider.slider("option", "min")){
            jQuery("#scroll_left").addClass('disabled');
                curSlider = slider.slider("option", "min");
        }

        scrollbar.slider('option', 'value', curSlider);                 

    }, timer_speed);


}


if( isTouch === false ){

    jQuery("#scroll_right").mouseenter(function(){
        jQuery(this).mouseenter_trigger_right();
    });

    jQuery("#scroll_left").mouseenter(function(){
        jQuery(this).mouseenter_trigger_left();
    });

    jQuery("#scroll_right,#scroll_left").mouseleave(function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
    });                 

}

function setScrollerWidth(){
    var origWidth = jQuery(".scroll-bar").width();//read the original slider width
    var sliderWidth = origWidth;//the width through which the handle can move needs to be the original width minus the handle width
    var sliderMargin =  (origWidth - sliderWidth) * 0.5;//so the slider needs to have both top and bottom margins equal to half the difference                  
    jQuery(".scroll-bar-wrap").css({ paddingRight: jQuery('.scroll-bar .ui-slider-handle').width() });//set the slider height and margins
    jQuery(".scroll-bar").css({ right: jQuery('.scroll-bar .ui-slider-handle').width() })

    jQuery('.scroll-bar .ui-slider-handle').text('::');

}

// Show the scroll-bar-wrap when all images are loaded
jQuery('#portfolioList img').imagesLoaded(function(){
    jQuery('.scroll-bar-wrap').show();
})
```

});

Thanks in advance, let me know if its possible and how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **click** function instead of **mouseenter** function

Use this code

```
// start right moving
jQuery("#scroll_right").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).mouseenter_trigger_right();
});

// start left moving
jQuery("#scroll_left").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).mouseenter_trigger_left();
});

// stop moving
jQuery("#scroll_stop").mouseleave(function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```

instead of below code.

```
jQuery("#scroll_right").mouseenter(function(){
    jQuery(this).mouseenter_trigger_right();
});

jQuery("#scroll_left").mouseenter(function(){
    jQuery(this).mouseenter_trigger_left();
});

jQuery("#scroll_right,#scroll_left").mouseleave(function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```